# Source of this quote by Hillel?

Tags: sources-mekorot

The following quote appeared in a book I was reading:

> “May I be punished, if my decision was not communicated
> to me by Shemaiah and Abtalion!” At once, his opinion was accepted.

The author attributes this quote to Hillel. What is the original source for this quote?

Comment: Which book?....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be from [Yerushalmi Pesachim 6:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Pesachim.39a.2?lang=bi):

> אע"פ שהיה יושב ודורש להן כל היום לא קיבלו ממנו עד שאמר להן יבוא עלי כך שמעתי משמעיה ואבטליון כיון ששמעו ממנו כן עמדו ומינו אותו נשיא עליהן.‏